# Views field: how to add html 'title' attribute to link

Tags: views, navigation

In views fields like [Content: Title] and [Content: Taxonomy] there is the possibility to have the content displayed as link. Is it also possible to equip these link with a html 'title' attribute?

Alternatively, is it possible to equip *all* links on a drupal site with html 'title' attributes?

Answer (score 3):

This will add title attributes to most links, depends with some modules though.

```
/**
 * Add title attribute to any link that doesnt have a title already
 */
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_link(&$vars) {
    // If title set and not empty dont do anything
    if (isset($vars['options']['attributes']['title']) && !empty($vars['options']['attributes']['title'])) {
        return;
    }

    // Use the link text as the title
    $vars['options']['attributes']['title'] = strip_tags($vars['text']);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways your issue can be addressed. Please find answers below that will resolve some of your questions.

- All Menu Links created using Drupal Core Menu Module i.e using User Interface

You can use [Menu Attributes](http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module to add title attribute.

- Links exposed in custom module

You can use [l function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) to create a link with attributes.

- Views fields

You can use rewrite results option to rewrite content and add html as you like with attributes to a tag.

**UPDATED:**

Uncheck the setting in title field settings as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I am however not using any menus on my site at all. I managed to achieve a rewrite for the Title field: 

`<div title = '[title]'> [title]</div>` 
(reads funny doesn't it? ;) But when I rewrite `<div title = '[field_taxonomy]'> [field_taxonomy]</div>`, the title gives the full URL...

Comment: I meant, the title popup shows the full html tag: `<a href="site.com/cat/foo">foo</a>`

Comment: You need to uncheck link setting in views title field settings... See my updated answer ! For taxonomy term you just need to print the term name with out any formatting.. Uncheck "Link this field to its term page"

Comment: I got it working for the title field, as I described above. Unchecking "Link this field to its term page" would remove the link. With field_taxonomy, I got it to work in plain text format, with the rewrite mentioned above and 'output field as link', link path `/cat/[field_taxonomy]` and path set absolute. Phew.